# How can I make my python scraping function execute between a certain range of post?

Tags: python, django, conditional-statements

I am a novice. I have created a function that scrapes between a certain amount of posts. It works, but it just seems so large and novice looking. I want to condense the code and make it behave in a way that will decrease the amount of posts it scrapes by 1 if the initial amount is to large. So if it tries to scrape 15 and there are only 14 it will drop to 14 instead of halting. heres my code

```
def scrape_world():
    url = 'http://www.example.org'
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = []

    if len(titles) > 15:
        titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:15]
        random.shuffle(titles)
        print(len(titles))

    elif len(titles) > 14:
        titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:14]
        # random.shuffle(titles)
        print(len(titles))

    elif len(titles) > 13:
        titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:13]
        random.shuffle(titles)
        print(len(titles))

    elif len(titles) > 12:
        titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:12]
        random.shuffle(titles)
        print(len(titles))

    elif len(titles) > 11:
        titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:11]
        random.shuffle(titles)
        print(len(titles))

    elif len(titles) > 10:
        titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:10]
        random.shuffle(titles)
        print(len(titles))

    elif len(titles) > 9:
        titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:9]
        random.shuffle(titles)
        print(len(titles))

    else:
        titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:8]
        random.shuffle(titles)
        print(len(titles))

    entries = [{'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
                'src': box.img.get('src'),
                'text': box.strong.a.text,
                } for box in titles]

    # random.shuffle(entries)

    return entries
```

I tried something like

```
if len(titles) > 15 || < 9:
```

but that did not work right

UPDATE: print(titles) output

```
[<section class="box">
<a class="video-box" href="/videos/video.php?v=wshh2Nw4BKk0vav380lx">
<img alt="" height="125" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/clPaWvb6lWk/maxresdefault.jpg" width="222"/>
</a>
<strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshh2Nw4BKk0vav380lx">Spodee - All I Want</a></strong>
<div>
<span class="views">18,781</span> 
<span class="comments"><a data-disqus-identifier="95018" href="http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshh2Nw4BKk0vav380lx#disqus_thread"></a></span>
</div>
</section>, <section class="box">
<a class="video-box" href="/videos/video.php?v=wshh058e7C1B1Ey8qwNT">
<img alt="" height="125" src="http://hw-static.worldstarhiphop.com/u/pic/2016/06/t9OWyXfcdYQm.jpg" width="222"/>
</a>
<strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshh058e7C1B1Ey8qwNT">Sheesh: Dude Grill Is On Another Level!</a></strong>
<div>
<span class="views">182,832</span> 
<span class="comments"><a data-disqus-identifier="95013" href="http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshh058e7C1B1Ey8qwNT#disqus_thread"></a></span>
</div>
</section>, <section class="box">
<a class="video-box" href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhrXYCnHFIj4h2GQjE">
<img alt="" height="125" src="http://hw-static.worldstarhiphop.com/u/pic/2016/06/M1itOMKyh7zj.jpg" width="222"/>
</a>
<strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhrXYCnHFIj4h2GQjE">Back At It: Brock Lesnar To Return At UFC 200, WWE Approved!</a></strong>
<div>
<span class="views">124,237</span> 
<span class="comments"><a data-disqus-identifier="95016" href="http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshhrXYCnHFIj4h2GQjE#disqus_thread"></a></span>
</div>
</section>, <section class="box">
<a class="video-box" href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhj7V8H8GXx08iH2V9">
<img alt="" height="125" src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/YRlsJtuZ09s/maxresdefault.jpg" width="222"/>
</a>
<strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhj7V8H8GXx08iH2V9">Jose Guapo - Off Top</a></strong>
<div>
<span class="views">16,462</span> 
<span class="comments"><a data-disqus-identifier="95017" href="http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshhj7V8H8GXx08iH2V9#disqus_thread"></a></span>
</div>
</section>, <section class="box">
<a class="video-box" href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhfOnhy45f780tHqQG">
<img alt="" height="125" src="http://hw-static.worldstarhiphop.com/u/pic/2016/06/wn03kuXW3v2a.jpg" width="222"/>
</a>
<strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhfOnhy45f780tHqQG">Tulsa Candidate Angry About Not Being Involved In The Mayoral Debate, Runs Up There Anyway!</a></strong>
<div>
<span class="views">115,333</span> 
<span class="comments"><a data-disqus-identifier="95014" href="http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshhfOnhy45f780tHqQG#disqus_thread"></a></span>
</div>
</section>, <section class="box">
<a class="video-box" href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhrYcD83QWN1n0665g">
<img alt="" height="125" src="http://hw-static.worldstarhiphop.com/u/pic/2016/06/14H17jc8ZTIw.jpg" width="222"/>
</a>
<strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhrYcD83QWN1n0665g">This Motel Has An Interesting Key Policy!</a></strong>
<div>
<span class="views">16,015</span> 
<span class="comments"><a data-disqus-identifier="95019" href="http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshhrYcD83QWN1n0665g#disqus_thread"></a></span>
</div>
</section>, <section class="box">
<a class="video-box" href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhs2kTRq49K0gXYbuu">
<img alt="" height="125" src="http://hw-static.worldstarhiphop.com/u/pic/2016/06/e2VMzdzmKwFe.jpg" width="222"/>
</a>
<strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhs2kTRq49K0gXYbuu">Yonio &amp; AG - Holy (Freestyle) [Houston Unsigned Artist] </a></strong>
<div>
<span class="views">4,076</span> 
<span class="comments"><a data-disqus-identifier="95012" href="http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshhs2kTRq49K0gXYbuu#disqus_thread"></a></span>
</div>
</section>, <section class="box">
<a class="video-box" href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhDQZ3eC6yJE6Y5hjL">
<img alt="" height="125" src="http://hw-static.worldstarhiphop.com/u/pic/2016/06/dVjLEzVRc1YQ.jpg" width="222"/>
</a>
<strong class="title"><a href="/videos/video.php?v=wshhDQZ3eC6yJE6Y5hjL">Messed Up: 6-Year Old Polish Boy Beats His Mother And Pulls Her Hair!</a></strong>
<div>
<span class="views">201,996</span> 
<span class="comments"><a data-disqus-identifier="95015" href="http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/videos/video.php?v=wshhDQZ3eC6yJE6Y5hjL#disqus_thread"></a></span>
</div>
</section>]
```

Comment: None of your criteria will be met here. You define `titles = []` before your first `if` check... well `len(titles)` is zero and since that never meets any of your criteria, it just falls through. Why are you trying to check the length of `titles` before defining it as `titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')`?

Comment: @roganjosh If I originally had it defined like this ' titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')[:15]' but it scraped nothing so i had to decrease the numbers manually to see what the number was. it turned out to be 8. i thought the set up I had would have solved that problem but it hasn't. So I changed titles =[] and it worked

Comment: I'm pretty sure it isn't actually working how you think though. Since `titles = []` has a length of zero, _everything_ will be funneled through the criteria defined for your `else`. I don't have experience with BeautifulSoup but it feels unintuitive that you would have to define the number of expected matches prior to scraping. Also, `[:15]` is a list slice, so if it returns a list object to you, that command isn't changing anything about how much is scraped, only the number of items in the list that are visible to you.

Comment: @roganjosh to be clear if I dont have [:15] I get this error ' 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' ', so I have to slice it like that. Now if I try scraping 15 and theres 14 I will get the same error message. How should I approach my situation?

Comment: Ummm, I'm a bit at a loss on this because I don't use BeautifulSoup. I'm almost convinced though that adding `[:x]` will not change the function call, it's a form of post-processing simply to cut down the results. I assume then that the error comes in `entries = `? Can you post a stack trace? Also, is `box` an import from BeautifulSoup because I can't see where it's defined otherwise.

Comment: @roganjosh i changed titles from this titles =[] to this titles[15] and it seems to be working. but the code is still to long

Comment: Actually, scrap that. Comment out `entries = ...` and put in `print titles` in its place. Copy/paste that output so we can all see what you are receiving (even if you have to obfuscate strings)

Comment: If you code works post on   http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think there's quite a few misunderstandings here. `len([15])` is one... the list has one item in it. If you can carry out my last request (I think my last request is the easiest to get a resolution for this) then I will have a go at answering.

Comment: Since your code repeats write a function for repeating code

Comment: @roganjosh box is the name of a div. entries isn't the issue. That I know I changed it to print like you asked but it just prints out the 8 posts because that's all it can grab at the moment because that's all that's available. You have helped me tho. having tiltles equal nothing doesn't help I gave it a number. but thank you. I think I just need to make a function as suggested

Comment: @losee if you _edit_ your question to include the printout of those 8 items, then I can probably help with this. I have a pretty good idea on what the problems are currently, but without that information to verify my thinking then it's impossible for me to _know_ that I'm giving helpful information. I think the way you describe the issues on your end is not actually accurate to the underlying issue.

Comment: @roganjosh I added it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better in your example to actually include the example of what you're trying to do so that it's easier for folks to repro your issue.

Like the comments say, your code is going straight to `titles[:8]` because before the loop, `titles =[]` which means `len(titles)` is 0. the `soup.find_all` function is smart enough to know how big your dataset is, so no need to specify the length. Based on your `print(titles)` output, I assumed your pointing your code at `url = 'http://www.worldstarhiphop.com'` so the below uses that. When scraping this specific url, there's a "SUBMIT YOUR VIDEO" result in `titles[11]` that's throwing an error when you build your `entries` dictionary. **roganjosh**'s answer is the right basic approach, but in this case it won't capture titles[11] which is not None, but unfortunately just a different format.  If you update cleaned_titles to be the below it should work for you.

```
cleaned_titles = [title for title in titles if title.a.get('href') != 'vsubmit.php']
```

giving you:

```
def scrape_world():
    url = 'http://www.worldstarhiphop.com'
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')

    cleaned_titles = [title for title in titles if title.a.get('href') != 'vsubmit.php']

    entries = [{'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
                'src': box.img.get('src'),
                'text': box.strong.a.text,
                } for box in cleaned_titles]
    return entries
```

Comment: @Matt That Worked better than I expected. It's scraping so much I have to put a limit on it now thanks. Now I can remove all those if statements

Answer (score 1):

Ok, BeautifulSoup returns a different type of structure than I was expecting. However, I did push for clarifications on the premise of an answer, so I will post and retract if there's an issue with this.

```
def scrape_world():
    url = 'http://www.example.org'
    html = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'html5lib')
    titles = soup.find_all('section', 'box')

    cleaned_titles = [title for title in titles if title is not None]

    entries = [{'href': url + box.a.get('href'),
                'src': box.img.get('src'),
                'text': box.strong.a.text,
                } for box in cleaned_titles]
    return entries
```